# OpenRefine - add sequence number, reset for each record

Tags: openrefine

I have some records containing multiple rows. I want to give each row within a record a unique ID based on the string in the first row, containing the original ID + _01 _02 _03 and so forth.

Then I would like the counter to reset when the next record with a new string begins, and repeat the above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following grel expression `value +row.index - row.record.fromRowIndex+1`  to generate the id. You can read more about row and record index here: http://kb.refinepro.com/2012/06/creating-row-and-record-index.html

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Also, thanks for the great website which has helped me a lot previously.